# Deleting a row in Table X based on the existence of a value in Table Y

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm completely new at SQL and have been at this for 6 hours now, to now avail. I must be missing something simple. In a nutshell: I want to delete a post in a Wordpress database based on a partial matching string in another table in the database.

Here's what I've got so far. It should explain what I'm trying to do:

```
CASE
WHEN option_value FROM wp_options LIKE '%domain.com%'
THEN DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = 'uniqueID'
ELSE DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
END
```

The ELSE and X's are there to make sure nothing changes if they don't match.

What am I missing? :-)

@Dan Bracuk This was the final code that did the trick:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_title = 
CASE
WHEN (SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE '%domain.com%' LIMIT 1) LIKE '%domain.com' THEN 'UniqueID'
ELSE 'XXXXXXX' 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql syntax is not valid.  It has to resemble this:

```
 delete from wp_posts
 where post_title = 
 case 
 when (subquery to get data from option_value table) like '%domain.com%' then 'uniqueId'
 else 'XXXXXXX' 
 end
```

However, it's probably better not to use a case construct here.  I would do something like this:

```
 delete from wp_posts
 where 
 (post_title = 'uniqueId'
 and somefield in
 (select somefield 
 from option_value
 where wp_options like '%domain.com%'
 )
 )
 or
 (post_title = 'XXXXXX'
 and somefield in
 (select somefield 
 from option_value
 except
 select somefield 
 from option_value
 where wp_options like '%domain.com%'
 )
 )
```

Note that some databases use the word minus instead of except and others simply don't support that syntax.  However, this gives you the general idea.

Comment: This was it! I didn't get your bottom answer to work but the first one was perfect after a little tweaking. It turned out it did return more than 1 row so I had to limit it to the top one and then work with that. Here's the final code:

DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_title = 
CASE
WHEN (SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE '%domain.com%' LIMIT 1) LIKE '%domain.com%' THEN 'UniqueID'
ELSE 'XXXXXXX' 
END

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a definitive answer without a bit more context. However, from an initial look at your code, assuming that it needs to adhere to standard SQL syntax, the following line would need updating from

```
option_value FROM wp_options LIKE '%domain.com%'
```

to

```
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE '%domain.com%')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Joseph! That is a push in the right direction. Thanks for pointing that out. An interesting way to  check it. However, it doesn't work. I get a syntax error when I enter this into PHPMyAdmin:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE '%domain.com%' at line 1  Let me know what extra information /context I can provide! I'll be happy to. It feels as if we're almost there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this , I believe it will help

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_options  WHERE post_title LIKE '%uniqueID%'))
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = 'uniqueID'
  END
ELSE
    BEGIN
     DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title  = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE '%domain.com%')
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = 'uniqueID'
END
```

You don't need the ELSE, if ELSE is just to do nothing :)